# Guice Java provides method without known dependency?

Tags: java, guice

The documentation for `provides` seems to be lacking so I am asking this question.

Consider this Guice module

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
  String TEMPLATE_PATH = '/path/to/templates';

  @Provides
  RateLimiter generateRateLimiter(UserPreferenceSelector prefSel) {
    return new EmailTemplate(new FileLocator(TEMPLATE_PATH), prefSel);
  }

  /* ...configure... */
}
```

For the method `generateRateLimiter` where is the `UserPreferenceSelector prefSel` fetched from? I don't see it being provided anywhere. How does it get created and what about the constructor of `UserPreferenceSelector`?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need a primer on dependency injection. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the binding resolution docs](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingResolution). When Guice makes a `Provider`, and the `Provider` has a parameter of type `A`, Guice tries to find a `Provider` or binding for `A`. Among the things Guice looks for (among the **last** things, i.e. if there's no other way to get `A`) is a default constructor. This is likely what's happening in your case: does `UserPreferenceSelector` have a default constructor?

Comment: Nope, `UserPreferenceSelector` doesnt have a default constructor. It has a constructor which is like `@Inject public UserPreferenceSelector (Dep1 dep1, Dep2 dep2, ...)`, what in this case happens?

Comment: @jnvjdbsuw Does Guice have a binding for all of those dependencies in that constructor?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike-, how can I check that? Noob to Guice here